# consolidating multiple column counts into a single query with Rails 4 Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Rails 4.1, Postgres 9.3, deploying to Heroku

I'm trying to reduce the number of calls to the DB.

I have a big table, surveys, with multiple boolean columns like `role_composer`, `role_performer`, and so forth.

The controller has multiple queries like

```
@sample = Survey.where(...whatever...)
@Composers = @sample.count("case when role_composer then true end")
...
@Performers = @sample.count("case when role_performer then true end")
```

This works fine, but results in many individual queries to the database that differ only by the expression in the select. Is there a way to construct this as one query with multiple aggregated/computed columns? I also have queries with average() and with expressions, but most common is count().

In postgres this works:

```
SELECT count(case when role_composer then true end) as "COMPOSERS", count(case when role_performer then true end) as "PERFORMERS" from surveys;
```

Any way to do this with Activerecord methods on @sample instead of resorting to find_by_sql()?

I've tried a variety of approaches without success: `.count().count()`, `.count([array])`, `.select("count(...) as col1, count(...) as col2")`, `.select(["count(...) as col1", "count(...) as col2"])`

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Using `find_by_sql()` might be the only way to consolidate the multiple counts into a single query. I don't think rails provides anything more.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to create a view, but that is only practical for subset of the queries. E.g count() & average().

Comment: What happened with your `select('count(...) as col1, ...')` approaches?

Comment: @mu, Activerecord seems to not recognize the aggregation and returns a relation instead of a single result. It also does not assign methods to the aliased column names, so no way to use the relation.
`a=@sample.select(["case when role_composer then true end as iscomposer","case when role_teacher then true end as isteacher" ])`
`a.iscomposer`

`NoMethodError: undefined method `iscomposer' for #<Survey::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000045e82e8>`
parens around the expression doesn't help

Comment: apologies for the format on the comment. Markdown didn't work out the way I thought.

Comment: Moving this comment up, so more visitors can see it.  
I since realized another way to handle this, taking advantage of the array-like qualities of a relation. A statement like 
`c=Survey.where(where_string).select('count(case when role_composer then true end) as composers')[0]`  
extracts the single survey object from the relation and you can then reference `c.composers` for the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.select("count(...) as col1, count(...) as col2")` version should work fine if you remember two things:

1. `M.where(...).select(...)` returns multiple things even if the query only returns one row.
2. Just because something doesn't appear in the `inspect` output doesn't mean it isn't there.

You're doing aggregates without a GROUP BY so you'll only be getting one row back. To unwrap that row, you can say `first`:

```
counts = Survey.where(...)
               .select('count(case when role_composer then true end) as composers,  count(case when role_performer then true end) as performers')
               .first
```

That will give you a `Survey` instance in `counts`. If you look at that `counts` in the console, you'll see something like this:

```
#<Survey >
```

The `inspect` output only includes values from columns (i.e. things that the `Survey` class knows about) but the `composers` and `performers` will be there. However, since ActiveRecord doesn't know what types they're supposed to be, they'll out as strings:

```
composers  = counts.composers.to_i
performers = counts.performers.to_i
```

Everything in your `select` will be there if go looking for it.

Comment: I had tried nearly exactly this [where.select.first.colname] in a single expression and got an error. Your conviction & example made me look closer, There is a subtlety that I cannot explain. If you exclude .first from the initial definition of counts it works. Including .first raises an exception. Other than that, you are exactly right & I will mark as the correct answer. Thank you! What is the correct way to update the example code so those who find this get pointed right? BTW, I'm not using inspect for this.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: In rails console, `Survey.where().select().first` produces a PG::GroupingError because an `order by surveys.id` clause is added. Bug in the postgres adapter, perhaps? Deferring the use of `first` or putting in a dummy `order` method avoids it. I suppose I should report this to the Rails bug collector?

Comment: The `.first` works fine in Rails3, I don't have any Rails4 things set up to check. Do you have a default scope or anything that is adding that ORDER BY or is it ActiveRecord pretending to know what it is doing? In any case, you should be able to throw a `to_a` in (`counts = Survey.where(...).select(...).to_a.first`) to get `Array#first` instead of whatever AR is trying to do.

Comment: Turns out this is by design in Rails 4 & is in the API docs, but coming from Rails 3 I didn't expect it. Using first() adds an order by on id. I worked around it at first by adding a dummy order by with .order("1").first. Better solution is to use take() instead of first(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I since realized another way to handle this, taking advantage of the array-like qualities of a relation. A statement like `c=Survey.where(where_string).select('count(case when role_composer then true end) as composers') [0]` extracts the single survey object from the relation and you can then reference `c.composers` for the result.