# Transform SQL query to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Issue:
I don't  know how to convert this PostgreSQL query:

```
select news_id, sum(case when likes.like then 1 else -1 end) as max_positive from likes group by(news_id) order by(max_positive) desc
```

to ActiveRecord Query.

What I tried:

```
Like.group(:news_id)
    .sum('CASE WHEN likes.like THEN 1 ELSE -1 end')
    .max_by { |_k, v| v }
```

But result is array and not select news_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Like.group(:news_id).select("news_id, SUM(case when likes.like then 1 else -1 end) as max_positive").order("max_positive desc")
```

Comment: it's not all good. Your query correct select id, but not sum. ` #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Like id: nil, news_id: 53>, #<Like id: nil, news_id: 46>, #<Like id: nil, news_id: 58>...`

Comment: @TomekWejchorowski: It is there but the model class's `inspect` doesn't know it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38270375/479863), just ask for it by calling the `max_positive` method on the returned model instances. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24131675/479863, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27494947/479863, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18351188/479863, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17714928/479863, ...

Comment: Thank you very much @lusketeer. Great links!